# Adding custom regression line with set intercept and slope to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, linear-regression

I have created a plot using the following code:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=damMean, y=progenyMean)) + 
    geom_point()
```

[image]

I want to overlay on the plot a regression line of the form: y = 69.88 + 5.58*x

I tried to do so by adding the following:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=damMean, y=progenyMean)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y~69.88+5.58*x)
```

But this doesn't add a line to the plot.

Is this possible to do using ggplot?

Comment: `+ geom_abline(slope=5.58, intercept=69.88)`

Comment: @DaveArmstrong this doesn't seem to have worked. There isn't any error message but the abline doesn't show on the graph

Comment: Just posted an answer that works for me.  I think the problem is that the regression line is not actually in the window.  For example, 5.58*40 + 69.88=289.88.  So, the line will contain the point (40,289.88).  Your y-axis only goes to around 110, so the line is not contained within the plotting region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example with some fake data:

```
mydat <- tibble(x=runif(100, 40, 90), 
                y = 80 + 5.5*x + rnorm(100, 0, 10))

ggplot(mydat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_abline(slope=5.58, intercept=69.88)
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great. Is there a reason why my `geom_abline(slope=5.58, intercept=69.88)` isn't showing on the plot?

Comment: See comment above.